# Unable to create a POJO class in spring boot. Getting error as "Not a managed type"

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have a query which returns columns from two different tables.And I've created a new POJO class to store the column data. But the POJO class throws error as **"Not a managed type".**

This error goes away when I add @Entity and @Id. But then I get error as ,

**Failed to convert from type [java.lang.Object[]] to type [@org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query com.library.model.entity.CatalogDisplay].**
Is it right to use @Entity since there is no actual table ?

```
package com.library.model.entity;


public class CatalogDisplay {


    private long bookid ;
    private String bookname ;


    public CatalogDisplay(long bookid, String bookname) {
        super();
        this.bookid = bookid;
        this.bookname = bookname;
    }

//has getters and setters
```

Repository class

```
@Repository
public interface BookCatalogRepository extends CrudRepository<CatalogDisplay, Long> {
    /**
     * Query to find all the books from catalog;
     */

    @Query ("Select bc.id , bd.bookname from  BookCatalog bc , BookDetails bd")
    List<CatalogDisplay> findAll() ;

}
```

Please let me know if this needs corrections or is there other way to write when columns from multiple tables are required.

Answer (score 0):

You miss the `@Entity` annotation on top of the `CatalogDisplay` class.

Also add `@Id` on to pf the bookid and make it to a Long

```
@Entity
public class CatalogDisplay {

    @Id
    private Long bookid ;
    private String bookname ;
```

Also remove the code from your interface, it is not needed

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen *and if this is the only problem, then you should vote to just close a typo question.*  missing of an annotation is not a typo for me

Comment: Actually, on second glance, you're right, and there are _no_ Hibernate annotations present at all.

Comment: I modified as suggested. But I still get error , No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.Long] to type [@org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query com.library.model.entity.CatalogDisplay]", @Jens

Comment: Can you please update yxour question with the code you have now?

Answer (score 0):

As the `CatalogDisplay` class seems to be a DTO or a view model I dont think annotating it with `@Entity` is the right way to go. I think what you want to do instead is to use the `new` operator in the jpql query so that the JPA provider creates the objects for you. Your query would then be `SELECT NEW com.library.model.entity.CatalogDisplay(bc.id , bd.bookname) from  BookCatalog bc, BookDetails bd`. This way you tell the JPA provider the constructor of which class to use.

Comment: Modified the query as you suggested and it worked! But I had to retain Entity and Id to avoid "Not a managed type" error.
Thanks!